# My images are not displaying on screen after using universal image loader

Tags: android

```
      public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    int mCurrentPage;
    Context c;
    GridView mListView;
    String id, cat;
    String strUrl;
    TextView tvtitle;
    TextView tv_id, tv_rating, tv_url;
    public static String img_url, img_rating, img_id, img_name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle data = getArguments();
        mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = null;
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.starters, container, false);
        tv_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id);
        tv_rating = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf);
        tv_url = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url);
        cat = Category.Main_Cat;
        Log.i("Logcat Cat1", cat);
        switch (mCurrentPage) {
        case 1:
            Log.v("MyFragment Heap", "Max Mem in MB:"
                    + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
            // strUrl =
            // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
            strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
            mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            Starter_info.class);
                    img_id = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText()
                            .toString();
                    img_rating = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf))
                            .getText().toString();
                    img_url = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText()
                            .toString();
                    img_name = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename))
                            .getText().toString();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            // strUrl =
            // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
            strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
            Log.v("Splash Heap", "Max Mem in MB:"
                    + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
            mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            Starter_info.class);
                    img_id = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText()
                            .toString();
                    img_rating = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf))
                            .getText().toString();
                    img_url = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText()
                            .toString();
                    img_name = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename))
                            .getText().toString();
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            Log.i("Cat IS", Category.Main_Cat);
            // strUrl =
            // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
            strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
            Log.v("Splash Heap", "Max Mem in MB:"
                    + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
            mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            Starter_info.class);
                    img_id = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText()
                            .toString();
                    img_rating = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf))
                            .getText().toString();
                    img_url = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText()
                            .toString();
                    img_name = ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename))
                            .getText().toString();
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            break;
        }
        return v;
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();
            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
        }

        return data;
    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        String data = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
            listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter> {
        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                StarterParser countryJsonParser = new StarterParser();
                countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
            }
            StarterParser countryJsonParser = new StarterParser();
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;
            try {
                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            String[] from = { "poster", "year", "duration", "id", "title" };
            int[] to = { R.id.iv_flag, R.id.tv_starter_hide_url,
                    R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf, R.id.tv_starter_hide_id,
                    R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename };
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity()
                    .getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

            return adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(getActivity());
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter
                        .getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                ImageView posterImage=((ImageView)adapter.getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.iv_flag));
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(imgUrl, R.drawable.img, posterImage);
                /*ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path", imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);*/
            }
        }
    }

    private class ImageLoaderTask extends
            AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>> {

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(
                HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream = null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory
                File cacheDirectory = getActivity().getBaseContext()
                        .getCacheDir();

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"
                        + position + ".png");

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOutStream);

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                // Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position
                // in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("flag", tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position", position);

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and
                // position
                return hmBitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            String path = (String) result.get("flag");

            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

            // Getting adapter of the listview
            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();

            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the
            // listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter
                    .getItem(position);

            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
            hm.put("flag", path);

            // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

     }

here is my imagelaoder class
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    int stub_id = R.drawable.img;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
    {
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }



          }
here is my starterparser class



    public class StarterParser {

    // Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
            public List<HashMap<String,Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

                JSONArray jCountries = null;
                try {       
                    // Retrieves all the elements in the 'countries' array 
                    jCountries = jObject.getJSONArray("Demo");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 // Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
                 // where each json object represent a country
                return getCountries(jCountries);
            }


            private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCountries(JSONArray jCountries){
                int countryCount = jCountries.length();
                List<HashMap<String, Object>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
                HashMap<String, Object> country = null; 

                // Taking each country, parses and adds to list object 
                for(int i=0; i<countryCount;i++){
                    try {
                        // Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country 
                        country = getCountry((JSONObject)jCountries.get(i));
                        countryList.add(country);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                return countryList;
            }

            // Parsing the Country JSON object 
            private HashMap<String, Object> getCountry(JSONObject jCountry){

                HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                String countryName = "";
                String flag="";
                String language = "";
                String capital = "";
                String currencyCode = "";
                String currencyName = "";       

                try {
                    countryName = jCountry.getString("id");
                //  flag = "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/admin/upload/"+jCountry.getString("Images");
                    flag="http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/admin/upload/img.png";
                    Log.i("imGE PATH", ""+flag);
                //  language = jCountry.getString("rank");
                    //capital = jCountry.getString("country");
                    currencyCode = jCountry.getString("duration");
                    currencyName = jCountry.getString("id");

                    String details =        "Price : " + language + "\n" +
                             "Rating : " + currencyCode + "\n";

                    country.put("id", currencyName);
                    country.put("poster", R.drawable.picture_frame);
                    country.put("flag_path", flag);
                    country.put("duration",currencyCode);
                    country.put("year", flag);
                    country.put("title", jCountry.getString("title"));
                    Log.i("Json Imag Name", jCountry.getString("poster"));


                } catch (JSONException e) {         
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
                return country;
            }

}
```

I have used image laoder concept in this, but it's not showing images on screen. Only the name and value of images are showing on logcat.

Answer (score 0):

In ListViewLoaderTask, onPostExecute method, check the Url pattern returned for.

```
String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
```

acceptable formats are

```
String imageUri = "http://example.com/image.png"; // from Web

String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card

String imageUri = "content://media/external/audio/albumart/13"; // from content provider

String imageUri = "assets://image.png"; // from assets

String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image; // from drawables (only images, non-9patch)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Volley Library WS calls and image downloads and caching, can be so easy to use it's like child's play... in the future try to implement Volley it makes your life easyer with only a  few line of codes:
A few tutorials:

[Volley tutorial 1](http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/)

[Volley tutorial 2](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/05/volley-easy-fast-networking-for-android.html)